# Flash builder mobile, Itemrenderer as form?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a FlashBuilder mobile app where I take a datasource and render various controls in a list using an itemrenderer, as this is an input form, when the various values have been entered (text and check box values) i want to then retrieve these values and store them in a local SQLite for later sync to a remote database.

So each row contains a label, a check box and a text box.

My question is how do I loop through the list and retrieve the values?

I guess my other question is have I done this the wrong way?

All comments valued

Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to put a form in a list. Could you elaborate a little? I'm just asking because you might have chosen the wrong control here. Did you choose the list because you want the form to be scrollable?

Comment: I am creating the form from a data source as the types of wquestions require different types of responses (text/checbox/toggleswitch etc)

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but why the `List`?

Comment: In my newbie mind that was the way to go. Happy to consider alternatives?

Comment: I would like to, that's why I'm asking. I still need a reason why you've chosen a list, otherwise it will be impossible to give you a viable alternative. I don't know your requirements, you know?

Comment: Thanks Al, perhaps I am using the wrong terms, what I am doing is taking my dataset (question_text, answer_type) and creating the controls based on the answer type, I add these elements to a HGroup and then I add these to a group within a scroller. Once the survey is complete I need to get the answers and store them.

Comment: Ok, I'm completely lost now. ;) I thought you were using a `List` control to create an input form (which isn't wrong, it just might be a little heavy for a mobile app)?

Comment: Sorry Al, my terminology use is perhaps not correct as I climb the learning curve :-)

Comment: No need for excuses, I'm just trying to understand your application design. But since you've solved the issue already, your solution probably works so far. You'll probably go through your code when you've got a bit more experience anyway and simplify it.

Comment: Thanks Al. The mist is slowly lifting :-{)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, one strategy would be creating a complex data type, for example:

```
public class MyType {
    public var name:String;  // use getter/setter would be even better
    public var checkedIn:Boolean;
    public var comment:String; 
}
```

and bind a list of such type to the list, then that gives your itemRenderer a complex type to bind to.  Your itemRenderer can then update the properties in MyType accordingly when checkbox or text input is updated.

By doing so, you don't have to loop through the list to retrieve the values.

However, in mobile control, having inputs in list could be an expensive choice of implementation.

Comment: thanks for the pointer mate, if it may be an expensive choice, what might be a cheaper alternative? :-)